# Borel-Cantelli lemma, exponential distribution problem

Tags: probability, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Good evening,

I am currently solving an exercise :
Let Xn be a sequence of independent random variables, each with the exponential distribution with rate $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.
I want to prove the part : $\limsup_{n \to \infty}  (\frac{X_n}{\log(n)}) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}$ a.s.

I found $\Pr\left(\frac{X_n}{\log(n)}\geq \alpha\right) = \frac{1}{n^{\alpha \lambda}},  \alpha >0$.

I used the Borel-Cantelli lemma with $\alpha > \frac{1}{\lambda}$ and the sum $\sum_{n \in   \mathbb{N}} \Pr(X_n 
 \geq \alpha \ln(n)) < + \infty$

In the end, I found $\Pr\left(\frac{X_n}{\log(n)}\geq \alpha 
\mbox{ i.o}\right) = 0
\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_n (\frac{X_n}{\log(n)}) \leq \alpha$ a.s.

How can I demonstrate that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_n (\frac{X_n}{\log(n)}) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}$ a.s. ?

Comment: Do you mean $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$? "\limsup_{n\to\infty}"...

Answer (score 1):

First, for any $\alpha>0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_n>\alpha\ln n)=n^{-\alpha\lambda}.
$$
The RHS is summable iff $\alpha>\lambda^{-1}$. Therefore, by the B-C lemma, $X_n>\ln n/\lambda$ i.o., but $X_n<(1+\epsilon)\ln n/\lambda$ ev. for any $\epsilon >0$. Thus, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n/\ln n=1/\lambda$ a.s.